# double space when exporting to TXT file in python

Tags: python, txt, tabulate, reactablefmtr

I have this code that works:

```
print((tabulate(email_list, showindex=False, tablefmt = 'plain')), file=open(output + '\\' + "np.txt", "w"))
```

but when I open the file, the email addresses look like this:

```
b  e  r  o  s  u  n  a  @  g  m  a  i  l  .  c  o  m
```

I have tried all the tablefmts and none work, I need it as plain text with no index and no headers left aligned because then I copy them and use it in another process.

Comment: What is `tabulate()`?

Comment: `email_list` should be a list of lists, I suspect it's just a list of strings. Each string is being treated as a list of characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks I just changed it completely:

```
emails = email_list.tolist()
textfile = open(output + '\\' + "np.txt", "w")
for element in emails:
    textfile.write(element + "\n")
textfile.close()
os.startfile(output + '\\' + 'np.txt')
```